# Does Maven eliminate IDE dependency?

Tags: maven

If our group uses Maven, will it promote IDE independence?

NetBeans generates a lot of project files that Eclipse doesn't use - if a developer creates something with NetBeans and Maven, can this project be directly ported to Eclipse using Maven?

Comment: just wondering what are the "a lot of project files"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've your pom.xml you can generate an Eclipse project with

mvn eclipse:eclipse

In general with Eclipse, I avoid committing any eclipse-specific artifacts to the source code repository, they are in my ignore file (in my case with Git, in .gitignore).

**UPDATE**: As for the comment regarding m2eclipse, then you can you can install m2eclipse plugin with Help -> Eclipse Marketplace. After installing it you can import the project from Eclipse with File > Import... > Maven > Existing Maven Projects.

Comment: mvn eclipse:eclipse is the old way to do it, it is no longer developed. [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) is now a core eclipse project and should be used for maven integration instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. You'll create one pom file and have all your source code, then you'll use different maven plugins to generate the project property files for each IDE.  For eclipse the command is mvn eclipse:eclipse same stands for flexbuilder and intelliJ I'm sure others as well.

Comment: Please don't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` - every modern IDE should have native Maven support.

Comment: Why? I've used the m2eclipse plugin but don't always find it that useful particularly when working with Flex projects wherein the builders for the project always shows the maven builder and flex builder if I have the plugin installed and it runs the build twice (I have to manually disable one if the m2eclipse plugin is installed).  I don't see any reason not to use the command line to get a project in condition for import (that is to generate the project property files).

Comment: I also do 99% of my SVN commands at the command line because Tortoise seems to do a lot of disk access and tends to mess up the icons (at least in vista, ugh).  Anyhow unless this command/plugin is somehow deprecated I don't understand the request to not use it.

Comment: Because it's very inconvenient. For instance when adding dependency or changing the project structure you have to regenerate and reimport the project in Eclipse. I don't know how it now works in Eclipse, but IntelliJ scans the `pom.xml` in real time and applies changes instantly, no need for reimporting.

Comment: if you have to change the dependencies you simply re-run the command and it generates the project properties file again including the new dependencies or properties, then you refresh in eclipse or at most close then open the project in eclipse and you're in good shape.  Honestly to me it's not worth it to have an extra plugin running in eclipse with flex and other plugins required for my work I find it to be intrusive and cause more problems than it solves

Comment: not trying to start a flame war or anything, I do like the plugin for it's pom wizard view so I use it to some degree but I feel when GUIs fail me command line always works and unless something is deprecated or otherwise going away or a bad practice for some other reason I don't see why you would recommend someone else change their way just because of what works for you.  Anyhow thanks for the thoughts, done with it :)